# Can GAE oauth tokens be made portable across different versions of one app?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

The docs say:

> Note that authorization is associated
>   with the domain used to access the
>   endpoints: an access token produced
>   using endpoints on one domain cannot
>   be used to access the app using a
>   different domain. If the access token
>   came from a version-specific
>   appspot.com domain, it can only be
>   used to access that version of the
>   app, and only at that domain.

However, this isn't the behavior that I'm seeing.  I have multiple versions of my app running against my custom domain (*not appspot!*), and when I switch which version is the default, all the tokens made with the version that *used to be the default* are no longer valid.  The invalidated tokens were made on the same custom domain that is now mapped to the newly default-ed version of the app, and yet they're still invalidated.  This basically destroys my ability to switch default versions, as doing so will inconvenience every single user.

Is this the expected behavior?  Is there any way to get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that it is supposed to happen; the actual version matters, Google doesn't care which version is the default.